# Suspending Testing State w/Capybara Automation and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

This is maybe a bit of an odd question, i've googled around and haven't seen any questions asked (But maybe im asking the wrong question).

So i've been rewriting Integration tests using Factories (Which is interesting, and thanks to the fine people at this site for your help!). But im pretty much relying on screenshots to see that what im wanting to happen in the tests is happening.

Im using a Test database (SQlite to be specific), and since im using Factories the data gets deleted of course once the test is over, so it's like it never happened. So running a server using the test environment I can't really "manually" verify the data.

Is there a good way to be able to manually verify the data? Like stopping the test RIGHT at the end or pausing it temporarily? I suppose I could put in a gigantic sleep...but surely there is a better way?

Comment: Have you considered making the things to be "manually verified" into expectations and including them in the test?

Comment: I do usually assert certain values, but it's still reassuring to be able to physically see everything "looks" right in your app.

Comment: I would advise the opposite approach, to wit: trust your tests. Make them so good that when the tests are all green, you have confidence that everything will work. If that isn't the case, fix them or write more tests.

If you *don't* feel that way about your tests, you will always be second-guessing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But a breakpoint in your test, then use whatever commands you like to query the db.

I use `gem 'pry-rails'` in my Gemfile

then you simply put the line `binding.pry` in the test and it will freeze there in the terminal and you can check variables, make db calls like `User.all` or `User.count` and if you also add the gem `pry-nav` you can navigate with `next`, `step`, `continue` etc

Comment: I've considered this but i've never found a decent guide at getting it set up. or is it literally just including the gem, and then calling the binding.pry in the test file.

Comment: yes very easy just as you say. add line to Gemfile `bundle install` then add `binding.pry` to code and run. the server terminal / or testing terminal will pull you up at the code.